# React event-handling (onClick) inconsistency

Tags: javascript, onclick, event-handling, reactjs

Sup.

**The following alerts on render, but not onClick:**

```
render: function(){
    return (
    <div onClick={alert('I alert on render, but not onClick.')} />
    );
}
```

**Same for the following:**

```
foo : function(text) {
    alert(text)
},
render: function(){
    return (
    <div onClick={this.foo('I also alert on render, but not onClick.')} />
    );
}
```

**This does nothing:**

```
foo : function(text) {
    alert(text)
},
render: function(){
    return (
    <div onClick={function(){this.foo('What is a click and what must I do with it, huh?')}} />
    );
}
```

**Although this works as expected:**

```
render: function(){
    return (
    <div onClick={function(){alert('I alert onClick only.')}} />
    );
}
```

Note that each code block exists inside a react class and that omitted styling creates an area that's clickable. Also note the alerts in the first two cases pop up twice each, but I believe this is because the web app uses react-router.

**I have two questions:**

1. For the first two cases, why do I need an anonymous function to prevent an alert on render?
2. Why does `foo()` not get called onClick in the 3rd case, but alert is triggered in the last case?

For Q1 I suspect my understanding of eventHandlers is a bit off and for Q2, well, I'm dumbfounded.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. For the first two cases, why do I need an anonymous function to prevent an alert on render?

What you have between curly braces is evaluated and hence showing the alert message on render.

> 2. Why does foo() not get called onClick in the 3rd case, but alert is triggered in the last case?

It is actually called but `this` is not the context you expect because you are creating an anonymous function. So inside that function the context doesn't have a `foo` method. You need some way to attach the proper context, for example, using [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
foo : function(text) {
    alert(text)
},
render: function(){
    return (
    <div onClick={this.foo.bind(this, 'What is a click and what must I do with it, huh?')}>click</div>
    );
}
```

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/9251/).

Answer (score 2):

In 1st and 2nd cases you just invoke functions inside {} brakets, they return nothing, but onClick field waits for function object inside {}. In 3rd and 4th cases you provide anonymous functions, which invoked when you click on div, but in 3rd case you call `this.foo(...)` inside anonymous function, and `this` refers to global `window` object, which has no `foo` method. You can modify your `foo` method to return function which shows alert with given text:

```
foo : function(text) {
    return function() {
         alert(text);
    }
},
render: function(){
    return (
        <div onClick={this.foo('I also alert on render, but not onClick.')} />
    );
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I figured it was my hazy understanding of scoping. I found that adding a `.bind(this)`, like so `onClick={function(){this.foo('Saved by bind!')}.bind(this)}`, also did the trick.

Comment: @LucasduToit This does the trick... but why create another function around the `foo` function. Just bind it to `foo` directly.

Comment: @dreyescat, I agree, there are plenty of possible solutions, one should decide which of them to choose. Moreover `bind` method usually create another function as well

Comment: @dreyescat Yup, simpler is better. Using your answer for my purposes - I need a bind to set the context for a `this.setState()` within my real function. Although @beshanoe answered Q2, it did not solve the underlying problem. Sorry beshanoe, I must accept dreyescat's answer!